# Как называется система, по которой модифицирован график? Пример с подробностью

Tags: c++, python, sql, mql

На входе два свечи A B. Свечу В преобразуем в С, в соответствии со следующей таблицей:

```
A B   C
0 0   1
0 1   0
1 0   0
1 1   1
```

На основе значений двух свечей A и B в новую базу записывается значение свечи C. Причём, время свечей:  timeA>timeB и timeC==timeB.  На MQL будет так C = ~(A^B).

Answer (score 1):

Это называется исключающее или. И в принципе, если гарантировать, что a и b могут быть либо 1 либо 0, то формула будет такая `c = 1-(a^b);` или так `int c = ~(a ^ b) & 0x01;`

Время свечей не имеет к вопросу никакого отношения.